# Javascript how to iterate and find a specific element inside a NodeList

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get all div element of a NodeList the problem is the list is consist of different items like text, comments, and HTML elements, what I want to get is the `div` element and append an id for each.

[image].

What I want to get is the list of `divs` below.

[image]

My current code is below my ListElements is the NodeList.

```
  var list = $( ".jssorb18" ).find( "span" );
  var listElements = list.prevObject[0].childNodes;

     listElements.forEach( 
        function(currentValue, currentIndex, listObj) { 

            console.log(currentValue); 

        } 
    );
```

And my output is below which is odd because I know there are 4 div elements or values on my NodeList, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post image....post actual code

Comment: @MamunI don't think I can type the console log output that is why it's an image.

Comment: But you can copy paste the console output, so we don't have to type all those nodes ourselves into a document to test.

Comment: Can you change how you get to this node list? If possible you could maybe change it to only include the required elements in the first place. E.g.: `document.querySelectorAll('div.some-class')`?

Comment: @Satpal i got an error querySelector is not a function.

Comment: Please post your HTML code!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator in order to check whether a node is a [DivElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement)
If you only need to append an id:

```
let divCounter = 0;
listElements.forEach( 
    function(currentNode, currentIndex, listObj) { 
        if (currentNode instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
            currentNode.id = 'myId' + divCounter++;
        }
    }
);
```

If you have to reuse those divs, you could also store them in a list:

```
const divList = [];
listElements.forEach( 
    function(currentNode, currentIndex, listObj) { 
        if (currentNode instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
            divList.push(currentNode);
        }
    }
);
```